# macOS : problem with setAllowedFileTypes and folder name

Tags: macos, nsopenpanel

I work on 10.14, if I wrote :

```
NSOpenPanel *panel;
NSArray* fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pdf", @"PDF", nil];
panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
int i = [panel runModal];
if(i == NSOKButton){
    return [panel URLs];
```

I can't navigate in folder with ".pdf" extension for exemple "test.pdf".

Anyone had already encountered this problem ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a general problem. If I create a folder named "test.jpg" with a file inside it, Safari can't open it. I apply "File>Open a file" in Safari and the folder appear like a file and I can't open it.

Best regards